# ruby: email.rb:11:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Net (NameError)

Tags: ruby, sendmail

The following:

```
require 'net/smtp'

message = <<MESSAGE_END
From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.com>
To: A Test User <test@todomain.com>
Subject: SMTP e-mail test

This is a test e-mail message.
MESSAGE_END

Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
smtp.send_message message, 'me@fromdomain.com',
           'test@todomain.com'
end
```

causes an error message:

> email.rb:11:in: uninitialized constant Net (NameError)

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you provide more details of the stacktrace? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?